# How to pass a variable in Xpath of an element identified using @FindBy annotation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, annotations, testng-eclipse

I am using Page Object Model (POM)for automating an application

I have identified elements using `@FindBy` annotation which has List of elements. Now, I want to iterate through all the elements. How can I do that.

Comment: Use a for loop or while loop to iterate... for(WebElement elem : listElements) {}

Comment: Thanks Grasshoper, Here, I want to loop along with passing a variable to xpath for each iteration. I want to know how to pass the variable into xpath

Comment: You should add some code,makes things clear. You can pass any variable to xpath expression by simple string concatenation.

Comment: `@FindBy(xpath=".//*[@class='TN GLujEb']//*/a[i]")`
`public List<WebElement> ind_leftpane;`

 //here 'i'  in xpath is the parameter i want to pass to the xpath in runtime

Answer (score 0):

Create a string array with the list of xpaths. Loop through the array and pass the xpath at (i) into the Find by variable.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Moser!
Sorry to say this that i did not get what you are trying to say.
Can you please ellaborate with an example here 

Thanks again!!